# Package Manager for Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode

I wasn't able to find the package manager by Alcatraz for Xcode 6.

I believe there is a substitute. I checked on their website but it said Mavericks and Xcode 5 only.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Alcatraz is supported for Xcode 6: https://github.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/issues/168

I haven't had any issue with it (yet)

Comment: And as stated in the comments at the given link, 'You have to shutdown xcode, during install alcatraz so that you can find "Package Manager" in "Window"'

Answer (score 1):

Alcatraz is available for OSX 10.9+ and Xcode 5+ only.

and Xcode 5+ only.

and Xcode 5+

Xcode 5+

5+

Xcode 6 is included 
:)

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the auxiliary_tools_for_xcode late 2012. It have PackageManager..

This PackagerManager is running on 10.10 and I am able to create sample.pkg and signing it.

Hopefully this help